# When you hover the .container it changes the color of both. But I just want to change it of the container where the mouse is on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-selectors

I prepared this:

http://jsfiddle.net/hXpWh/2/

When you hover the .container it changes the color of both. But I just want to change it of the container where the mouse is on.

Here is the js code:

```
moped = "";
$(".container").mouseenter(function () {
    $(".content").css('background', function () {
        moped = $(this).css('background');
        return "green";
    });}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(".content").css('background', function () {
        return moped;
    });
});
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="caption">
        <p>This is the caption of .container</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container2">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="caption">
        <p>This is the caption of .container2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    z-index: 800;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.container2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 255px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 800;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.content {
    display: block;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 900;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}
.caption {
    display: block;
    background: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}
.caption p {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Would it kill you to copy just *one more* snippet of code from your fiddle after you've done two of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers show what's wrong in the jQuery code, but another fix is to just using CSS for this.

Give the outer elements a common class, then:

```
.cont {
    background:red;
}
.cont:hover .content {
    background: green;
}
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/hXpWh/4/

---

But with respect to the jQuery code, not only do you need to find the nested `.content`, but also, there's no need for the variable. Just set the background to `""` in the `mouseleave`.

```
$(".container").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find(".content").css('background', "green");
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find(".content").css('background', "");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `$(".content")` to `$(this).find(".content")` in the `.mouseenter` function, and it will only change the one that you hover over. You could change it to `$(".content", this)`, but as per epascarello in the comments, it is not as efficient.

Comment: context selector has poor performance, better to use `$(this).find(".content")`

Comment: @epascarello Oh, I wasn't aware. Thank you for that, I will update answer with that as the suggested use.

Comment: this is what i was looking for. thanks. thats the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/hXpWh/5/

Comment: I just did a benchmark, the difference in Chrome 28 is about 6%. Not huge, but not negligible. http://jsperf.com/context-vs-find-js-or-jq

Comment: @Barmar I like knowing performance things like that, so it's definitely something I will keep in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Well , you could either move the css background attribute or do this:

```
moped = "";
$(".container").mouseenter(function () {
   $(this).children(".content").css('background', function () {
        moped = $(this).css('background-color');
        return "green";
    });
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).children(".content").css('background', function () {
        return moped;
    });
});
```

My advice is do it with the script and refactor it , use `.hover()` and name the `mouseenter` and `mouseout` functions separately.
 Good luck, mate.